# What is "the" Lua root for context packages?

Tags: context, best-practices, lua

As package author, I want to write a Lua module which can be found by both `lualatex` and `context`.

The `lualatex` prototype works reasonably and I am convinced that this will also be true if I release the package.

However, the `context` prototype does not find my files, but I can force it to find my files by specifying a suitable `LUAINPUTS` environment variable (which points to the directory from which my files can be found directly).

However, I do not understand if (or how) my package will work in the "wild" where this environment variable is *not* set as in my development environment.

The question is essentially: where should I place my files such that `context` can `require` it?

Here is what I believe to be a minimal working example:

Let us assume that my package resides in `/tmp/luamodule/texmf/tex/generic/pgfplots/libs/foo/bar/xyz.lua` . This resembles my vague idea that `texmf` will be the global `texmf` entry point, then I have my package (directories `tex/generic/pgfplots/libs`) and then I have a sub-directory structure resembling my Lua package (`foo/bar/xyz.lua`).

The package file `xyz.lua` contains the advanced package

```
io.write("\nFOUND IT!\n")
```

Then I have a file containing

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\directlua{require('foo.bar.xyz')}

\begin{document}

OK.
\end{document}
```

Processing this with

```
export LUAINPUTS="/tmp/luamodule/texmf/tex/generic/pgfplots//:"
lualatex xyz.tex
```

works: I see "FOUND IT" in the console output.

Next, I retry the same with `context` and write a file `xyzcontext.tex` containing

```
\directlua{require('foo.bar.xyz')}
\starttext
OK.
\stoptext
```

Translating this with

```
export LUAINPUTS="/tmp/luamodule/texmf/tex/generic/pgfplots//:"
context xyzcontext
```

fails because it cannot find the Lua file.

However, it works if I write

```
export LUAINPUTS="/tmp/luamodule/texmf/tex/generic/pgfplots/libs/:"
context xyzcontext
```

The difference is that my first LUAINPUTS path contains a recursive include (`//`) whereas the second one contains the precise root directory.

I have learned already that `context` does things differently compared to `lualatex` (does not use `kpse` during `require` and handles periods differently). But this issue lets we wonder: `lualatex` appears to work with recursively defined lua file paths. Judging from the texmf.cnf configs shipped with tex live, I would expect that my directory naming scheme will work. But what with context!? Will it find my files if I do not set such a root path? It seems that this kind of naming scheme works will with PGF's graph drawing lib (in both `lualatex` and `context`), but I don't really see why.

I even tried to copy my `.lua` files into the TL 2014 global `texmf` tree (followed by `texhash`) -- without success.

Thus, my question: where should I place my `.lua` files such that both `lualatex` and `context` can find them?

related:
[Best Practices for Lua Modules](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212198/best-practices-for-lua-modules)

Comment: Did you run ``mtxrun --generate`` to recreate the filename database? That should make files in the TEXMF available to Context’s lookup routines.

Comment: [… continued] Also, Context code rarely calls ``require()`` to load packages, usually only for external, non-TeX libs. Instead it’s more idiomatic to use [``environment.loadluafile()``](https://bitbucket.org/phg/context-mirror/src/69d17e62dd57cce4d59d020319edf1c5121f4319/tex/context/base/luat-env.lua?at=beta#cl-127) at the Lua end, and [``\registerctxluafile``](https://bitbucket.org/phg/context-mirror/src/69d17e62dd57cce4d59d020319edf1c5121f4319/tex/context/base/luat-cod.mkiv?at=beta#cl-72) from TeX.

Comment: @phg I was unware of `mtxrun --generate`. I ran it right now without any apparent difference (i.e. it still does not find the file).

Comment: @phg your reference to `environment.loadluafile` is new to me. Is that the solution? I have also received input from some context guy that `dofile(resolvers.findfile("foo.bar.whatever.lua"))` is (part of?) a best-practice. Admittedly, this only increases my confusion on how to write LUA libraries which are supposed to be used from within both `lualatex` and `context`.

Comment: ... perhaps an answer to my question might be a switch of sorts "if I am context else if I am lualatex ..."

Comment: If the file isn’t found after ``--generate`` then perhaps it’s located in the wrong tree? Modules from the Garden usually reside in the ``texmf-modules``, stuff that you install manually goes under ``texmf-local``. That’s assuming you’re using the Minimals, of course. There are certain conventions regarding file locations. Most files of third party modules belong under ``tex/context/third/${MODULE}/``, scripts that are supposed to be called from ``mtxrun`` under ``./scripts/context/lua/third/${MODULE}``, but I don’t think that convention is enforced when doing file lookups.

Comment: Here’s a suggestion for debugging path lookup:
First determine where Context stores its file info. Usually this is a directory named ``luatex-cache/context`` under the root ``texmf-cache`` or ``texmf-var``.
Then create a dummy file with a unique name somewhere under your ``texmf-local/``.
Now run ``mtxrun --generate`` and grep the ``luatex-cache`` recursively for the name of the dummy file.
If the file was found it will show up in a description of tree contents (``luatex-cache/context/<hash>/trees/<hash>.lua``).
If not, then the location isn’t traversed by Context at all.

Comment: Btw. one of my packages works in Context, Plain, and Latex: https://bitbucket.org/phg/enigma/src -- I just verified that placing the files in the respective trees under the ``texmf-local`` works just fine.

Comment: @phg thanks for your patience and time! That solved it! I placed the file into `/home/ludewich/tl2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/foo/bar`, ran `mtxrun --generate` and it was indexed properly and my minimal ran. I thought I had done the same after your first comment, but perhaps I made some mistake? If you write your hint regarding mtxrun into an answer, I will happily accept it.

Comment: @phg Do you mind writing an answer?

Comment: @phg just another friendly ping :) If you don't have time to write an answer, that's fine – just let us know :)

Comment: @Sean Allred I’d probably write an answer but this judgemental
site claims I’m a robot and won’t let me disprove that by means
of a captcha. That issue persists for half a year or so now and
I’m not interested in wasting any more time on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*For the sake of having a community wiki answer that can be upvoted to take this question off, and that I might reformat if it gets enough upvotes/requests, here are the comments:*

Did you run mtxrun --generate to recreate the filename database? That should make files in the TEXMF available to Context’s lookup routines. – Philipp Gesang Dec 25 '14 at 15:53

[… continued] Also, Context code rarely calls require() to load packages, usually only for external, non-TeX libs. Instead it’s more idiomatic to use environment.loadluafile() at the Lua end, and \registerctxluafile from TeX. – Philipp Gesang Dec 25 '14 at 15:53

@phg I was unware of mtxrun --generate. I ran it right now without any apparent difference (i.e. it still does not find the file). – Christian Feuersänger Dec 25 '14 at 17:31

@phg your reference to environment.loadluafile is new to me. Is that the solution? I have also received input from some context guy that dofile(resolvers.findfile("foo.bar.whatever.lua")) is (part of?) a best-practice. Admittedly, this only increases my confusion on how to write LUA libraries which are supposed to be used from within both lualatex and context. – Christian Feuersänger Dec 25 '14 at 17:34

... perhaps an answer to my question might be a switch of sorts "if I am context else if I am lualatex ..." – Christian Feuersänger Dec 25 '14 at 17:35

If the file isn’t found after --generate then perhaps it’s located in the wrong tree? Modules from the Garden usually reside in the texmf-modules, stuff that you install manually goes under texmf-local. That’s assuming you’re using the Minimals, of course. There are certain conventions regarding file locations. Most files of third party modules belong under tex/context/third/${MODULE}/, scripts that are supposed to be called from mtxrun under ./scripts/context/lua/third/${MODULE}, but I don’t think that convention is enforced when doing file lookups. – Philipp Gesang Dec 27 '14 at 11:36

Here’s a suggestion for debugging path lookup: First determine where Context stores its file info. Usually this is a directory named luatex-cache/context under the root texmf-cache or texmf-var. Then create a dummy file with a unique name somewhere under your texmf-local/. Now run mtxrun --generate and grep the luatex-cache recursively for the name of the dummy file. If the file was found it will show up in a description of tree contents (luatex-cache/context//trees/.lua). If not, then the location isn’t traversed by Context at all. – Philipp Gesang Dec 27 '14 at 11:44

Btw. one of my packages works in Context, Plain, and Latex: bitbucket.org/phg/enigma/src -- I just verified that placing the files in the respective trees under the texmf-local works just fine. – Philipp Gesang Dec 27 '14 at 11:55

@phg thanks for your patience and time! That solved it! I placed the file into /home/ludewich/tl2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/foo/ba‌​r, ran mtxrun --generate and it was indexed properly and my minimal ran. I thought I had done the same after your first comment, but perhaps I made some mistake? If you write your hint regarding mtxrun into an answer, I will happily accept it. – Christian Feuersänger Dec 27 '14 at 14:10